# Looping in React, how to get a prop.username from child component

Tags: javascript, loops, reactjs

I have this code, which renders a Friends List block. Next to the name, there is an action dropdown menu, where there are several buttons, i need to seperate each button and on which user it belongs. So far it works, but outputs all the usernames, one by one. Check on the dropdown menu the onClick Alert. There when i press the href, nothing happens, though, when new content loads, it pops up alert foreach user listed.

```
var UserDropdownActions = React.createClass({
  handlesendMessage: function(username){
    console.log(username);
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
    <div className="tbl-cell tbl-cell-action">
            <div className="btn-group">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-rounded btn-primary-outline dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Connect
              </button>
              <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="javascript:;" onClick={alert(this.props.username)}><span className="font-icon font-icon-home"></span>Quant and Verbal</a></li>
                <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="javascript:;"><span className="font-icon font-icon-cart"></span>Real Gmat Test</a></li>
                <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="javascript:;"><span className="font-icon font-icon-speed"></span>Prep Official App</a></li>
                <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="javascript:;"><span className="font-icon font-icon-users"></span>CATprer Test</a></li>
                <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="javascript:;"><span className="font-icon font-icon-comments"></span>Third Party Test</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
  }
})
var UserDisplayNameFields = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div className="tbl-cell">
          <p className="user-card-row-name status-online">{this.props.username}</p>
          <p className="user-card-row-location">{this.props.hobby}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
var UserPreviewCircularImage = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div className="tbl-cell tbl-cell-photo thumbnail-wrapper d32 circular inline m-t-5">
        <a href={"/user/" + this.props.username}>
            <img src={this.props.avatar} alt={this.props.username} />
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var UserSmallView = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="friends-list-item">
          <div className={"user-card-row user_" + this.props.username}>
            <div className="tbl-row">
              <UserPreviewCircularImage avatar={this.props.avatar} username={this.props.username} />
              <UserDisplayNameFields username={this.props.username} hobby={this.props.hobby} />
              <UserDropdownActions username={this.props.username} />
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var FriendList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {

     return ( 
    <div className="friends-list">
    {
      this.props.users.map( (user, i) =>  {
        return(
        <UserSmallView
            key={i}
            username={user.username}
            hobby={user.hobby}
            avatar={user.avatar} />
        )
      })
    }
    </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that i was trying to send to the function the username, though, it was already there.

i added a function where it alerts the prop.username

```
handlesendMessage: function(){
  alert(this.props.username);
},
```

instead of,

```
handlesendMessage: function(username){
  alert(username);
}
```